# [Python in Dockerfile], how can I find out what is the correct order of packages in the "Requirements.txt" file?

Tags: python, docker, pip, requirements.txt

Hi  I'm building a simple Docker Image for Python and I'm struggling to find out what is the correct order of packages in Requirements.txt.

It failed in middle of executing when it hit the beow line in Dockerfile

```
RUN  pip install  -r requirements.txt
```

I put the output in the below as error.

***anyone knows how to find out ?***

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-buster

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Microsoft SQL Server Prerequisites (installing ODBC Drivervin Linux))
RUN apt-get update \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list \
        > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        locales \
        apt-transport-https \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
        unixodbc-dev \
        msodbcsql17 


RUN pip install --upgrade pip   

RUN  pip install   -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 5000
```

**requirements.txt**

```
flask==1.1.1
SQLAlchemy==1.1.15
pyodbc==4.0.21
simplejson==3.13.2
matplotlib==2.1.0
scikit-learn==0.20.2
surprise==0.1
scikit-learn==0.20.2
O365==1.1.5
pandas==0.23.4
numpy==1.14.0
scipy==1.0.0
```

**error**

```
 Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mubf1uaz/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-mubf1uaz/pyodbc/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-v2ateps5 --python-tag cp37
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-mubf1uaz/pyodbc/
  Complete output (55 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'pyodbc' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.21 -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c src/buffer.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/buffer.o -Wno-write-strings
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.21 -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c src/errors.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/errors.o -Wno-write-strings
  src/errors.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* GetErrorFromHandle(Connection*, const char*, HDBC, HSTMT)’:
  src/errors.cpp:332:44: warning: ‘Py_ssize_t PyUnicode_GetSize(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       if (!msg || PyUnicode_GetSize(msg.Get()) == 0)
                                              ^
  In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/Python.h:99,
                   from src/pyodbc.h:45,
                   from src/errors.cpp:2:
  /usr/local/include/python3.7m/unicodeobject.h:793:24: note: declared here
   PyAPI_FUNC(Py_ssize_t) PyUnicode_GetSize(
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/errors.cpp:332:44: warning: ‘Py_ssize_t PyUnicode_GetSize(PyObject*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       if (!msg || PyUnicode_GetSize(msg.Get()) == 0)
                                              ^
  In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/Python.h:99,
                   from src/pyodbc.h:45,
                   from src/errors.cpp:2:
  /usr/local/include/python3.7m/unicodeobject.h:793:24: note: declared here
   PyAPI_FUNC(Py_ssize_t) PyUnicode_GetSize(
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.21 -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c src/cnxninfo.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/cnxninfo.o -Wno-write-strings
  src/cnxninfo.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* GetHash(PyObject*)’:
  src/cnxninfo.cpp:45:88: warning: ‘PyObject* PyUnicode_EncodeUTF8(const Py_UNICODE*, Py_ssize_t, const char*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       Object bytes(PyUnicode_EncodeUTF8(PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(p), PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(p), 0));
                                                                                          ^
  In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/Python.h:99,
                   from src/pyodbc.h:45,
                   from src/cnxninfo.cpp:7:
  /usr/local/include/python3.7m/unicodeobject.h:1320:23: note: declared here
   PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_EncodeUTF8(
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/cnxninfo.cpp:45:88: warning: ‘PyObject* PyUnicode_EncodeUTF8(const Py_UNICODE*, Py_ssize_t, const char*)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
       Object bytes(PyUnicode_EncodeUTF8(PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(p), PyUnicode_GET_SIZE(p), 0));
                                                                                          ^
  In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.7m/Python.h:99,
                   from src/pyodbc.h:45,
                   from src/cnxninfo.cpp:7:
  /usr/local/include/python3.7m/unicodeobject.h:1320:23: note: declared here
   PyAPI_FUNC(PyObject*) PyUnicode_EncodeUTF8(
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.21 -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c src/pyodbcdbg.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/pyodbcdbg.o -Wno-write-strings
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.21 -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c src/getdata.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/getdata.o -Wno-write-strings
  src/getdata.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* GetDataDecimal(Cursor*, Py_ssize_t)’:
  src/getdata.cpp:405:38: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
           pch = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(result, &cch);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
  Running setup.py clean for pyodbc
```

Comment: it seems that scipy need numpy so put scipy after numpy will solve the problem I think

Comment: check the dependencies for each package with `pip show <package name>`. The Requires field will show the dependencies for the package. Then order the requirements.txt according to the dependencies.

Comment: @LinPy , you are great !, I went one step a head but face a differnet error, I will update the question details in a minute!

Comment: for the new eror you should install unixodbc-dev and python3-dev with apt-get I think

Answer (score 0):

As @LinPy said, for pip the requirements files are taken in order so you just need to reorder the packages according to their own dependencies.

For the second problem did you check the pyodbc required components: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install
In particular they mention unixodbc-dev package.

Since you are having issue with encoding it would be worth also to double check your locale.

Comment: Thanks - How can I find out what is the correct order?

Comment: @TocToc , I did not write all that as an answer because that did not answer the OP question `How can I find out what is the correct order` copying what I said in the comments will not help .....

Comment: @LinPy: I did just so just to have enough lines. 
As far as I know there is no easy way: probably want to look at https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/ but that assumes you already made once the correct order.
I personally go through the release notes of the different package to build my requirements files.

Comment: I appriciate your helps guys!